# Profile Edit form using Solspace User is submitting without going to 'return' parameter template

Tags: solspace-user

I have a Solspace User v4.0.9 form setup to edit Member Custom Fields, in EE 3.5.10

However, when editing the fields and submitting, all the form fields empty and the 'return' template isn't loaded. It feels like the form is being submitted by jQuery or something weird, but I have no idea how, as I haven't set it up like that.

> {exp:user:edit return="account/billing/updated" form:class="rd-mailform text-left"}

Yet, if I edit the Member in EE, all the correct data has been saved to the Custom Fields.

If I then manually refresh the frontend form, all the data appears correctly in the form fields.

I don't get it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason this is happening, but I don't understand why.

I had the following CartThrob code in the form, but when I comment this out, the Solspace User form works normally.

> {exp:cartthrob:customer_info}
>        {exp:cartthrob:country_select id="country_code" name="country_code" selected="{country_code}" extra='required'}
>   {/exp:cartthrob:customer_info}

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd look at the output code (with and without) and see, if by using carthrob tag, carthrob isn't injecting its own form tag as well.